# How to properly integrate HTML5 Boilerplate with JQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, html5boilerplate

I am using the HTML5 Boilerplate and would like to incorporate JQuery UI. Adding the JS doesn't seem like a big deal:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery.ui || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

But how would I incorporate the CSS file? Would I just call it after the HTML5BP style.css is called?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css">
```

Comment: I don't think that it would make a difference because those 2 will not interact in some way but I would place the jquery css after the every other css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is yes. Just place the jquery link after the H5BP link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

In style.css, you have an "author section", between the normalisation section and the last section about media queries, non-semantinc helper classes, etc.

Either copy-paste the whole of jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css in the author section, as if it was part of your own code, or if you want to separate things, add an @import rule there. Read the docs http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/  : css page and build script page.